# How to scroll up/down a UICollectionView while moving one of its components near of its borders?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, drag

So I have a scrollabble `UICollectionView` with multiple row/column.

[image: What it looks like actually]

I'm able to add what I'm calling a PostIt (the red/yellow/green squares at the right) in each of the `UICollectionViewCell`. Then I'm also able to move each of this PostIt between each `UICollectionViewCell`.

What I would like to do is when I'm dragging (slowly) one PostIt near of the top/bottom of the `UICollectionView` it will scroll up/down the `UICollectionView` .

I know how to have the `UICollectionView`'s scrollbar position with: `_collectionView.contentOffset.x` (or with `_collectionView.contentOffset.y` but i don't really care about this one).

I think it could be possible if I was able to compare the coordinates of the center of the PostIt with top/bottom of the collection view with something like `if(the center of the postIt is near of the top/bottom) then {scroll up/down}`.

But I dont really know how to process, if someone could help me it will be nice! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more simple than you thought!

I did this once with `UITableView`. `UICollectionView` should act similar. You have to implement `UIScrollViewDelegate` This code should help you:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (scrollView == self.firstTableView)
    {
        [self.secondTableView setContentOffset:scrollView.contentOffset];
    }

    else if (scrollView == self.secondTableView)
    {
        [self.firstTableView setContentOffset:scrollView.contentOffset];
    }
}
```

We can tell how much `UITableView` is scrolled (and change it) from its property `contentOffset`. The position of *PostIt* could be defined from another scroll view (if we are using it) or the coordinates while dragging. When the *PostIt* is near the desired position - change the `contentOffset` or scroll the `UICollectionView` to desired index path.

Comment: What are your first and second tableView representing?

Comment: The idea of this example is that since one scroll view is scrolled, another scroll view is scrolled together by changing content offset. Imagine that the first `UITableView` represents your `UICollectionView` and the second one -  your element.

Comment: So I need to add one more UICollectionView?

Comment: Not necessarily. You want to add a component which moves together with the component while `UICollectionView` scrolls, right? So, this component is likely to be a component with a `UIScrollView`. It doesn't matter which UI element is it, `UICollectionView`, `UITableView`, `UIScrollView` and etc. If you want to provide different kind of element location change than scrolling together, you can get the `UICollectionView` scrolling change according to `contentOfset` and move your element wherever you want. Using `UIScrollView` to move the element (as you see) is way easier though.

Comment: I dont really know if you have understood what I want to do. And I didn't really understand what you want me to do so i'll explain it in 3 steps:
1) I begin to drag the postIt
2) The postIt is actually dragged near of the top/bottom of the collection view
3) Now, the collection view is scrolling top/down, which will allow me to add the posIt in the cells who are bellow (what we can't actually see on the picture. Is that what you have understood before?

Comment: The similar way as it is in SublimeText editor? You drag PostIt and `UICollectionView`scrolls while dragging PostIt?

Comment: I'm not using the sublime text's editor. I'm looking for an other exemple without success...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109575/discussion-between-tom-kortney-and-kokodelo).

Comment: If you think my answer is helpful, please mark it as a correct answer.